# how to analyze data in aws athena from postgresql pg dump in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

I have taken pg dump of large tables (>50 GB) in AWS S3 in csv.gz format from postgresql RDS. I want to store this data into AWS athena in the form of actual tables as in the RDS, so that when requirement is there i can directly use the data without restoring those tables in the RDS.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: The data needs to be in a format that is supported by athena such as JSON or CSV, or you need to use AWS glue to transform the data. What you're basically looking for is an ETL process. A raw psql dump is probably not a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each file contains data from one table in CSV format, you can create a table to query that data.

I find the easiest way is to use **AWS Glue**:

- Put each file relating to a table in a **separate subdirectory** in S3
- **Create a crawler** in AWS Glue, pointing it to the directory
- It will automatically create **a table in Amazon Athena** that lets you query the data

If you wish to improve performance of the queries, I would recommend that you **convert the data into Snappy-compressed Parquet format**.

From [Examples of CTAS queries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
      format = 'Parquet',
      write_compression = 'SNAPPY')
AS SELECT *
FROM old_table;
```